# Problem about deformation theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I'm reading Evans PDE, on chapter 8.5 the proof of deformation theorem about the calculus of variation.

On page 504 Evans wrote on the top: "we verify that the map $u\to dist(u,A)+dist(u,B)$ is bounded below by a positive constant on each bounded subset of $H$." Who knows how to check this?

Some of my thought, if there is a subsequence $u_k$ such that the sum tends to $0$. Then we deduce $dist(A,B)=0$, as we know the distance between a close set and a compact set are positive, but the bounded subset of $B$ may not be compact. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I:m also trying to show it to no avail

Answer (score 0):

If this is not true, we can find bounded
sequences $u_k\in A$ and $v_k\in B$ such that $\Vert u_k-v_k\Vert$ tends to zero. From boundness we have $I'[u]<M$ for some constant $M$. Set $a_k(t)=u_k+t(u_k-v_k)$, since $$\frac{d}{dt}I[a_k(t)]=(I'[a_k(t)],a_k'(t))=(I'[a_k(t)],u_k-v_k)$$
We have $\epsilon-\delta\leq |I[a_k(1)]-I[a_k(0)]|\leq \sup|\frac{d}{dt}I[a_k(t)]|\leq M\Vert u_k-v_k\Vert\to 0$, which is a contradiction.